# avoid updating date modified field of installed files

Tags: date, dll, installation, nsis

I am trying to figure out how to avoid updating the 'date modified' field of files when using nullsofts scriptable install system. In particular a .dll file's date modified field is used to determine whether or not the dll needs to be updated.

However once the installer is run the dll's date modified field is updated to the current time, preventing me from using this field to determine 
whether or not the dll needs to be updated.

Any ideas?? This does not seem to be an issue with msi.

Comment: NSIS isn't a Windows Installer / MSI technology.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SetDateSave` instruction controls this:

```
SetOutPath $temp
SetDateSave on ; This is the default
File "Foo.dll"
SetDateSave off
File "Bar.dll"
```

Comment: Is there a particular location to place this in the .nsi file? I would like to retain the creation date for all files used by the installer.

Comment: The global default is "on" so all you have to do is to not use `SetDateSave off`

Comment: Very strange, as the folder(and all subfiles) in which the files are installed have an updated 'date modified' field (to when they were installed). Is there any way to check if this command is being overridden in another place?

Comment: Do I have to place the SetDateSave before specific files?